# CrossCorrelation of images

Tags: c#, fft, correlation, complex-numbers

I used the Accord Framework to implement the cross correlation between two images. My goal is to find by how much (how many pixels, and in which direction) the second image is shifted compared to the first one.

The basic formula I used is the following :

- `corr(a, b) = ifft(fft(a_and_zeros) * conj(fft(b_and_zeros)))`

I'll put the whole code at the end of my message, everything happens on a Click event. My initial images were stored in 1024*768 bitmaps. So here is the steps I have taken :

1. I cropped the 2 images into the 4 zones that were interesting for me (`ExpInit, ExpFinal, RefInit, RefFinal`), that I want to correlate two by two (`ExpInit` with `ExpFinal` and `RefInit` with `RefFinal`). Those cropped images have dimensions of 1024*131.
2. I put those cropped images in the center of new bitmaps with 2^n dimensions (2048*512).
3. Applied a `Grayscaling` filter to get `8bppIndexed PixelFormat`.
4. Converted each image to `ComplexImage`format and applied forward FFT on the 4 images.
5. Complex-conjugating every elements in the `RefFinal` and `ExpFinal` fourier-transformed `ComplexImage`.
6. Execute element-wise multiplication between the `ComplexImage`objects I want to cross-correlate (`ExpInit` with `ExpFinal`, `RefInit` wit `RefFinal`).
7. Apply the backward FFT to the product of the element-wise multiplication. Tadaaa, my cross-correlation is done, and I have two `Complex[,]` objects with the dimensions of my images (2048*512 pixels)

Now I want to answer my initial question : by how much (how many pixels, and in which direction) is the ExpFinal (respectively RefFinal) image shifted compared to the ExpInit (respectively ExpFinal). Here I am left puzzled.

I have the intutition I should be drawing a 3D graph with my `Complex[,]` object, where x and y are the index in the array, and z the value at the index, and search for the max value, but how do I do that with complex numbers ? Do I use only the Re part ? Only the Im part ? The amplitude ? Or am I completely mistaken ?

Bonus question : what is a good library for drawing such graphs ?

Here is the whole code for the described cross-correlation :

```
        private void crosscorrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cropping all 4 sections (RefInit, ExpInit, RefFinal, ExpFinal) and placing them in the center of new Bitmaps with 2^n dimensions
        Rectangle rExp = new Rectangle(1, 157, 1024, 131);
        Bitmap ExpInitCrop = new Bitmap(rExp.Width, rExp.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ExpInitCrop);
        g.DrawImage(BMInit, -rExp.X, -rExp.Y);
        Bitmap ExpInitLarge = new Bitmap(2048, 512);
        using (Graphics largeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(ExpInitLarge))
        {
            largeGraphics.DrawImage(ExpInitCrop, 513, 190);
        }
        Rectangle rRef = new Rectangle(1, 484, 1024, 131);
        Bitmap RefInitCrop = new Bitmap(rRef.Width, rRef.Height);
        Graphics h = Graphics.FromImage(RefInitCrop);
        h.DrawImage(BMInit, -rRef.X, -rRef.Y);
        Bitmap RefInitLarge = new Bitmap(2048, 512);
        using (Graphics largeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(RefInitLarge))
        {
            largeGraphics.DrawImage(RefInitCrop, 513, 190);
        }
        Bitmap ExpFinalCrop = new Bitmap(rExp.Width, rExp.Height);
        Graphics i = Graphics.FromImage(ExpFinalCrop);
        i.DrawImage(BMFinal, -rExp.X, -rExp.Y);
        Bitmap ExpFinalLarge = new Bitmap(2048, 512);
        using (Graphics largeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(ExpFinalLarge))
        {
            largeGraphics.DrawImage(ExpFinalCrop, 513, 190);
        }
        Bitmap RefFinalCrop = new Bitmap(rRef.Width, rRef.Height);
        Graphics j = Graphics.FromImage(RefFinalCrop);
        j.DrawImage(BMFinal, -rRef.X, -rRef.Y);
        Bitmap RefFinalLarge = new Bitmap(2048, 512);
        using (Graphics largeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(RefFinalLarge))
        {
            largeGraphics.DrawImage(RefFinalCrop, 513, 190);
        }

        // Grayscalling the 4 sections to get 8bppIndexed PixelFormat
        Accord.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale filterGS = new Accord.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        Bitmap RefFinalLargeGS = filterGS.Apply(RefFinalLarge);
        Bitmap ExpFinalLargeGS = filterGS.Apply(ExpFinalLarge);
        Bitmap RefInitLargeGS = filterGS.Apply(RefInitLarge);
        Bitmap ExpInitLargeGS = filterGS.Apply(ExpInitLarge);

        // FFT on the 4 sections
        Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage ExpInitComplex = Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(ExpInitLargeGS);
        ExpInitComplex.ForwardFourierTransform();
        Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage RefInitComplex = Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(RefInitLargeGS);
        RefInitComplex.ForwardFourierTransform();
        Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage ExpFinalComplex = Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(ExpFinalLargeGS);
        ExpFinalComplex.ForwardFourierTransform();
        Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage RefFinalComplex = Accord.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(RefFinalLargeGS);
        RefFinalComplex.ForwardFourierTransform();

        //Conjugating the ExpFinal and RefFinal section
        Complex[,] CompConjExpFinal = new Complex[ExpFinalComplex.Height, ExpFinalComplex.Width];
        Complex[,] CompConjRefFinal = new Complex[RefFinalComplex.Height, RefFinalComplex.Width];
        for (int l = 0; l < ExpFinalComplex.Height; l++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < ExpFinalComplex.Width; m++)
            {
                CompConjExpFinal[l, m] = System.Numerics.Complex.Conjugate(ExpFinalComplex.Data[l, m]);
                ExpFinalComplex.Data[l, m] = CompConjExpFinal[l, m];
            }
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < RefFinalComplex.Height; l++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < RefFinalComplex.Width; m++)
            {
                CompConjRefFinal[l, m] = System.Numerics.Complex.Conjugate(RefFinalComplex.Data[l, m]);
                RefFinalComplex.Data[l, m] = CompConjRefFinal[l, m];
            }
        }

        //Element-wise multiplication of the complex arrays two by two
        Complex[,] ExpMultipliedMatrix = new Complex[ExpFinalComplex.Height, ExpFinalComplex.Width];
        Complex[,] RefMultipliedMatrix = new Complex[RefFinalComplex.Height, RefFinalComplex.Width];
        for (int l = 0; l < ExpFinalComplex.Height; l++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < ExpFinalComplex.Width; m++)
            {
                ExpMultipliedMatrix[l, m] = System.Numerics.Complex.Multiply(ExpInitComplex.Data[l, m], ExpFinalComplex.Data[l, m]);
                RefMultipliedMatrix[l, m] = System.Numerics.Complex.Multiply(RefInitComplex.Data[l, m], RefFinalComplex.Data[l, m]);
            }
        }

        //InverseFFT
        Complex[,] CrossCorrExpMatrix = new Complex[ExpFinalComplex.Height, ExpFinalComplex.Width];
        Complex[,] CrossCorrRefMatrix = new Complex[RefFinalComplex.Height, RefFinalComplex.Width];
        Accord.Math.FourierTransform.FFT2(ExpMultipliedMatrix, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
        Accord.Math.FourierTransform.FFT2(RefMultipliedMatrix, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
        CrossCorrExpMatrix = ExpMultipliedMatrix;
        CrossCorrRefMatrix = RefMultipliedMatrix;
    }
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imaginary part of the result should be 0 (or within numerical error). To find the shift you should be looking at the location of the peak of the correlation's amplitude (but unless you've got one is the negative image of the other, that's likely to correspond to the peak of the correlation's real part). The main thing to be careful about: since you centered both images, an extra shift (of half the image size) will be introduced.

As for viewing the graph, you could fairly easily map the result to a grayscale image and view it with your favorite image viewer.

Comment: I'm going to test this, thanks. As for the extra shift you're mentionning, can I get rid of it by aligning my images in the top-left corner of the bitmap ? Would if be problematic for the cross-correlation ?

Comment: You could get rid of the extra shift by making the center of the images in the top-left corner with wrap-around (so that you get 1/4 of the image in 4 corners of the bitmap in a swapped fashion), like would be done with matlab's [`fftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html)..

Comment: in 2024 I would look at Feature Based Alignment Like SIFT which to be fair was Proprietary in 2018. In addition to Shift. There is also Rotation and Translation to worry about. In addition all of this is Synchronous. This is something that would benefit dramatically from Parallelization. Even on a four core processor you are talking 4-5x faster, on a 12 or 16 core you are talking about doing this 10x faster and in Todays world with 4K images everywhere Alignment is enormously computationally expensive.